# Node.js Promises are not being executed in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, promise

Before I start an web server, I'd like to create a few local directories for config files and what not

```
// app.js
var fsPromise = require('./fs-promise.js');
var httpPromise = require('./http-promise.js');
var promise = require('promise');

promise.all([fsPromise.createDir('configs'), fsPromise.createDir('logs')])
  .then(httpPromise.startServer());

// fs-promise.js
var fs = require('fs');
var promise = require('promise');

module.exports = {
    ...
    createDir: function(directory) {
        return new promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
            //console.log('Creating new dir: ' + directory);
            var newDir = __dirname + "\\" + directory;
            fs.mkdir(newDir, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Created new dir: ' + directory);
                    fulfill();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

// http-promise.js
...
module.exports = {
    startServer: function() {
        return new promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
            http.listen(configParams.server_port, function() {
                console.log('Server is running on port ' + configParams.server_port);
                fulfill();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

However, the console printout looks something like this:

```
Server is running on port 3000
Created new dir: configs
Created new dir: logs
```

Why are the directories being created first? Shouldn't Promise.all return a new promise that is only satisfied when all the input promises are completed?

Comment: FYI, it is common in "startup" code that is only called once at server initialize time to simplify things and use synchronous file operations.  This is one of the few times that synchronous I/O may make sense.  In case you're unsure of that, just remember that `require()` uses synchronous file I/O for this same reason (it drastically simplifies startup code).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. In that case, I think I may just go with the synchronous fs operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the result of calling the function `httpPromise.startServer` instead of the function *itself*:

This should fix the issue:

```
promise.all([fsPromise.createDir('configs'), fsPromise.createDir('logs')])
  .then(httpPromise.startServer);
```

The `.then` function takes a callback function as an argument.  A raw promise here cannot be executed correctly.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!